# python - AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Row' object has no attribute 'JobCount'

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have a query that's grabbing data from a database and returning the values so I can parse.

```
def executeScriptsFromFile(monitor):
    # Open and read the file as a single buffer
    fd = open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'sql/{0}.sql'.format(monitor)), 'r')
    if args.alias:
        sql_query = fd.read().format("'" + args.alias + "'")
    else:
        sql_query = fd.read()
    fd.close()

    # Execute SQL query from the input file
    cursor.execute(sql_query)
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    return result
```

The query can differ so I'm trying to build in logic so it will skip part if `JobCount` isn't one of the values.

```
query_data =  executeScriptsFromFile(args.monitor)
print query_data
if query_data.JobCount:
    print query_data.JobCount
else:
    send_status = send_data(job_data)
    print send_status
```

Unfortunately I get the following traceback.  How do I ignore the value if it isn't there?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tidal-zabbix.py", line 92, in <module>
    if query_data.JobCount:
AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Row' object has no attribute 'JobCount'
```

Comment: Are you sure the result has that attribute to it? I would assume since its a DB query that you would need to do query_data[0],  query_data[1] etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check whether `'JobCount'` is an attribute of `query_data` use `hasattr()`

```
if hasattr(query_data, 'JobCount'):
    print query_data.JobCount
else:
    send_status = send_data(job_data)
    print send_status
```

Comment: Alternatively, use eg. `getattr(query_data, 'JobCount', False)` to get a default value if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Dolda2000 That way tou can't tell appart the cases where the attribute doesn't exist from those where the attribute does exist and has the default value. Unless we know that `.JobCount` will never be `False`, that is likely true but we can´t really be sure. If you want to get a value regardless the attribute exists or not use `getattr()`, if you want to tell whether the attribute exists or not use `hasattr()`.